# Failed to read strings

Tags: c++

```
printf("c1=");
scanf("%c", &c1);
printf("c2=");
scanf("%c", &c2);
printf("a=");
gets(a);`
```

I want to read 2 characters and one string. The problem is that it doesn't work this way. Can you give me some alternatives? Without `cout` and `cin`, if possible.

Comment: "Without cout and cin" - Why? Those are the standard ways to perform io on the standard input/output streams in C++.

Comment: @iani - `He's Romanian` That didn't stop `A. Alexandrescu` from learning proper C++ coding.

Comment: How is the input data formatted?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it doesnt work? Give more explanation about it. If c2 is not taking the input, use a space before %c: scanf(" %c", &c2).
Comment if the problem is not this one

Answer (score 0):

Take this input for example:

```
a b abc
```

it first reads 'a',  then ' ', then the string 'b'.
Do this:

```
scanf("%c %*c %c %*c %s",&c1,&c2,&string)
```

the * character means that the current integer/character/string etc. will be ignored.